# Permissions Error Manipulating PDFs using GraphicsMagick (GM) on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: pdf, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, graphicsmagick

I created a function on Google Cloud that manipulates images once they are uploaded to Google Cloud Storage.

The function works well with nearly all the images types I require to support, except when I get to PDF handling. I am trying to convert PDFs to Images and I get the following error:

```
Failed to resize path/75/ae4d8a49-ea8e-4473-a679-14a372e2afba_rear.pdf. Error: Command failed: identify-im6.q16: not authorized `/tmp/ae4d8a49-ea8e-4473-a679-14a372e2afba_rear.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412.
```

Upon googling this error, I found out is related to policies and suggest editing a `policy.xml` file (https://cromwell-intl.com/open-source/pdf-not-authorized.html). However, this does not seem to be possible within Google Cloud Function.

Any ideas on how I can manipulate PDFs within Google Cloud Functions?

Note: This may be related to [Google cloud function permission problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48406271/google-cloud-function-permission-problems)

Comment: Are you using the in-built ImageMagick described in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions#example_image_transformation)? If you are, indeed it's not possible to change the configuration files of that library, as it would expose Cloud Functions to certain risks, as commented on the link you provided, however, you can import other libraries and configure them as you see fit, you can check how in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs). Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Yes that is the built in ImageMagick (GraphicsMagick) I am using. What other library would I need to use in this case?

Comment: You can try to use the same ImageMagick module actually, but using the whole module locally and when deploying refering to it in your `package.json` using the `file: prefix` notation. as described in [this section of the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs#including_local_nodejs_modules_as_part_of_your_deployment_package), let me know if it works.